# Remove Stopwords before indexing or after retrieving using zend-search-lucene

Tags: php, zend-search-lucene

I just started using zend-search-lucene,i need suggestion how to remove the stop words while indexing or while retrieving the search results.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at this implementation: http://codefury.net/2008/06/a-stemming-analyzer-for-zends-php-lucene/